# Is this probability statement logically equivalent to the original statement?

Tags: probability, logic

Does the probability that $\Pr \left[ {A < {R_3} \cup B < {R_2}} \right]$ with the information that ${R_3} < {R_2}$ logically equivalent to $\Pr \left[ {\min \left[ {A,B} \right] < {R_3}} \right]$ or should the statement be $\Pr \left[ {\max \left[ {A,B} \right] < {R_3}} \right]$ ?

In case my thinking is wrong, is there anyway to construct something like this:

$\begin{gathered}
  \Pr \left[ {\max \left[ {A,B} \right] \lessgtr {\text{some}}\,{\text{function}}\,{\text{of}}\left( {{R_2},{R_3}} \right)} \right] \hfill \\
  \Pr \left[ {\min \left[ {A,B} \right] \lessgtr {\text{some}}\,{\text{function}}\,{\text{of}}\left( {{R_2},{R_3}} \right)} \right] \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$

Note that $R_3$ and $R_2$ are two positive number and $A,B$ are non-negative random variable.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think your question has anything to do with probabilities. It is about the relative strength or possible equivalency of the conditions

$a)$ $A<R_3$ or $B<R_2$

$b)$ $\min\{A,B\}<R_3$

$c)$ $\max\{A,B\}<R_3$

on some real numbers $A,B,R_2,R_3$, **assuming** that $R_3<R_2$. Observe that $(b)$ is the same as $A<R_3$ or $B<R_3$ and $(c)$ is the same as $A<R_3$ and $B<R_3$.

First of all, clearly $c\Rightarrow b$ but $b\not\Rightarrow c$ (since it is possible that $A<R_3<B$). Also, $c\Rightarrow a$ since under $c$, $A<R_3$, but $a\not\Rightarrow c$ (since you can have $R_3<B<R_2$). Finally,  $c\Rightarrow a$ but $a\not\Rightarrow c$, since it is possible $R_3<B<R_2$.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, if $R_3=1,R_2=2$, and $A,B$ are random variables with the constraints $A\ge 1$ and $1\le B < 2$, then
$$
\Pr \left[ {A < {R_3} \cup B < {R_2}} \right]=1
$$
but
$$
\Pr \left[ {\min \left[ {A,B} \right] < {R_3}} \right]=0
$$
and
$$
\Pr \left[ {\max \left[ {A,B} \right] < {R_3}} \right]=0
$$

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much!. I have one more thing going in my head, is there anyway to construct something like this $\Pr \left[ {\max \left[ {A,B} \right] \lessgtr {\text{some}}\,{\text{function}}\,{\text{of}}\left( {{R_2},{R_3}} \right)} \right]$ or $\Pr \left[ {\min \left[ {A,B} \right] \lessgtr {\text{some}}\,{\text{function}}\,{\text{of}}\left( {{R_2},{R_3}} \right)} \right]$

Comment: @Tuong Nguyen Minh: What you're asking is not ckear. What is given?

Comment: Again, the information that $R_3 < R_2$ is given

Comment: @Tuong Nguyen Minh: Still not clear. But as my example illustrates, you should do some testing before proposing eqiavelences or implications.